# Can't load files from node_modules on localhost

Tags: angular, .htaccess, angular-cli, node-modules

I'm new in Angular CLI. I tried to update my project to Angular CLI and to Angular 4, but I get the following errors in the Chrome's console:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js 
GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js 
GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js 
GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js 
GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js 
Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined
        at systemjs.config.js:6
        at systemjs.config.js:45
    (anonymous) @ systemjs.config.js:6
    (anonymous) @ systemjs.config.js:45
Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined
```

It looks like the files with 'node_modules' are not found.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test app</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
      integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
      <fca-app>Loading...</fca-app>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" 
      integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" 
      integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
      integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

systemjs.config.js:

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      'app': 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        meta: {
          './*.js': {
            loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
          }
        }
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

I run the app with `npm start` (with `ng serve`).
I'm on localhost. Is that the problem (I don't have any .htaccess)?

Comment: Ah, so Angular CLI doesn't need these things anymore, that's why.

Comment: This is a very old version of angular cli. The latest is 1.0.0 and it uses Webpack and not SystemJs. I believe they switched from SystemJs in beta.12 or something.